# How to extract data from postgresql jsonb object in multiple levels

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table that contains json data with an 'signatures' array occurring multiple levels:

```
{
  "packet": "data"
  "signatures": [
    { "packet": "data" },
    { "packet": "data" }
  ]
  "userIds": [
    {
      "packet": "data",
      "signatures": [
        { "packet": "data" },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I know how to get all the signatures that occur on one level, i.e. all the signatures directly on the "packet" or all the signatures on all "userIDs":

```
select string_agg(signature->'packet'->>'data', ',') 
from keys, 
jsonb_array_elements(doc->'userIDs') userID, 
jsonb_array_elements(userID->'signatures') signature
```

But is there a way to extract all the signatures without knowing on which level they are?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: Obviously your query does not yield any results on the example data. Please, edit the question and deliver actual json data, the query and the expected results in the way that the example is verifiable. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can use `jsonb_each` (and `jsonb_array_element`) with a recursive CTE to traverse arbitrary JSON structures. But really I would recommend to avoid storing data whose structure you do not know.

Comment: select '{ "packet": "data" ,"signatures": [ { "packet": "data" }, { "packet": "data" }],
  "userIds": [ {"packet": "data","signatures": [  { "packet": "data" }]}]}'::json#>'{signatures}'  this can be used. but you have array in key, so you need to loop through array.